# O último item da ListView é sempre apagado, mesmo apagando um item no meio do ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

Possuo um `Adapter` qualquer e, ao clicar em um ícone de exclusão, o item do meu `ArrayList` é removido. O problema é que, mesmo removendo o item desejado, o `ListView` é atualizado, removendo sempre o último elemento. O curioso é que se eu adiciono um novo item ao `ArrayList`, a lista é atualizada com os valores reais.

Eis meu código:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //final ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;
    final int pos = position;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.adapter_product_list, null);

        //holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (productList.size() > 0) {
            //Product name
            final Product product = productList.get(position);
            final TextView productName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productName);
            productName.setEnabled(false);

            //Edit Button
            ImageButton editButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.editButton);

            //Delete button
            final ImageButton  deleteButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
            deleteButton.setTag(position);

            try {
                if (productName != null)
                    productName.setText(String.valueOf(product.getDescription()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Listeners
            editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    productName.setEnabled(true);
                    productName.requestFocus();
                }
            });

            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getRootView().getContext());

                    Integer tag = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    newDialogBuilder(tag);

                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    String yes = context.getResources().getString(R.string.yes);
                    String no = context.getResources().getString(R.string.no);

                    builder.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.areYouSureDelete))
                            .setPositiveButton(yes, dialogDelete)
                            .setNegativeButton(no, dialogDelete).show();

                }
            });

        }
    }
    return v;
}

private void newDialogBuilder(final int position) {
    this.dialogDelete = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                    productList.remove(position);
                    ProductListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    break;
            }

            ProductListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Exemplo: 
- Minha lista possui {1,2,3,4}
- Removo o 3 {1,2,4}
- Só que, o ListView exibe {1,2,3}, mesmo meu ArrayList não contendo o 3, e contendo o 4.

Obrigado! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elimine a linha `if (v == null){` e o respectivo `}`.

Da forma como está esse bloco só é executado quando a `convertView` for nula, quando não é, então será reaproveitada uma view usada por outro item, fazendo com que o valor guardado na *view.tag* não corresponda à *position* do item clicado.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado! Era realmente o que eu queria!